# Returning a variable instead of its assigned range

Tags: python, arrays

So I'm trying to write a program that calculates the date from a day out of the year (out of 365) and I'm having this problem in which I cannot get my for loop to work properly with python's range function. I.e.\

```
Day = input("Enter day: ")
january = range(1,32)
february = range(32,59)
etc....
months = [january,february,etc....]
for i in months
    if Day in i:
        return i
```

However this only ever returns range(x,y). I need it to return a position in the months array. Such as if day is 31 then it should return the [0] position (i=0), if day is 360 then it returns [12]. Is my for loop written wrong? My other solution to this would be telling it to return the variable name instead of what range it has assigned to it, however I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: write your complete code instead of _etc...._.

Comment: Rather than using `range()`, you could store the number of days in each month and then use plain addition as you loop through the list of days in each month.

Comment: @TeraByte The "etc...." here is pretty clear to elide the `range()` for each individual month.

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer to your question is to user `enumerate()` to give the index:

```
for month, i in enumerate(months):
```

However, this seems like an overly complicated way to solve this problem. An alternative solution is to store the number of days in each month:

```
months = [31, 28, 31, etc.]
```

Then use plain ol' arithmethic as you loop over this list:

```
for days, month in enumerate(months):
    if Day <= days:
        return month+1, day
    Day -= days
```

Note that this completely eliminates the need for you to calculate the first and last number for each month. I don't know about you, but I'd rather let the computer do the math than do it myself. Also, I still use enumerate here. Finally, I am returning both the month number and the day which basically reconstructs the calendar date. The `+1` is to make January start at 1 instead of 0.

Comment: ah that makes sense, so basically if it isnt in january, add the days in january to february. If its not in "january+february" then add that to march. I did figure out a way by storing the variable as an array of a range and a string so it checks [0] if its in the range and then prints [1] (the month) if its in that range. I will be refining it so this'll be very helpful

Comment: @Sam yes, an approach using addition instead of subtraction will also work

Answer (score 0):

A python range has the `.index(value, [start, [stop]])` function, giving the index of a value in the range.
This returns the first index of the value found, or raises a ValueError if it is not present.

Answer (score 0):

Just return the index of `i` in `months`. Also, note, if `Day` is `31` and it returns the `0`, then `Day=360` should return `11` since the last index of `months` is `11` not `12`.

```
Day = input("Enter day: ")
january = range(1,32)
february = range(32,59)
etc....
months = [january,february,etc....]
for i in months:
    if Day in i:
        return months.index(i)
```